# Changing a value from another class

Tags: c++, class

Ok, So I have a `Character .h/.cpp`, an `Enemy .h/.cpp`, and a `Driver.cpp` If I am creating my Character in my Driver, how do I create methods that will manipulate the character from the Enemy class?

Ex.

```
Driver: Character* character = new Character();
```

Now, in my Enemy file, I want an enemy's action to be able to change the `character's` values (life, hp, etc). I know I cannot use character->setHP(whatever) because the `Enemy` file doesn't know the `character` exists... Is there a way to do this?

Sorry if this is confusing.

EDIT:

Ok, so if I pass the `character` into the function, i have

```
ENEMY.CPP: void Enemy::enemyAttack(Character *character)
{ //whatever needs to be done }
```

which works fine.

But back in my `Driver`, if I do this:

```
Character *character = new Character();
Enemy::enemyAttack(character);
```

I get the following error message: "A nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object." is `character` not a specific object?

Comment: Maybe pass in the character into the enemy when you want to update?

Answer (score 1):

> I want an enemy's action to be able to change the character's values (life, hp, etc). I know I cannot use character->setHP(whatever) because the Enemy file doesn't know the character exists... Is there a way to do this?

You can decouple your `Enemy` and `Character` classes through an interface(implemented as an abstract class) that serves as a change notifier in your `Enemy` class. Consider the following design:

**Enemy  Class**

```
class Enemy{

   //your stuff
   enemyChangeListener ch;
   public:
      Enemy(/*your members*/,enemyChangeListener echl){
           /*your initialissation*/
           ch = echl;
      }

   //the method where you want to call a change on the character or any other object
   void enemyAttack(){
      //....//
      ch.fireEnemyAttacked(/*whatever args that describe the prop change in enemy object*/)
   }
```

**enemyChangeListener Class**

the `enemyChangeListener` class is just an abstract class that has just one (maybe more) method : `fireEnemyAttacked` as follows :

```
class enemyChangeListener{

      public:
       virtual void fireEnemyAttacked(/*args*/)=0;

}
```

**Character class**

Now, inside your character  class, you can just inherit from the enemyPropertyChanged abstract class and provide an implementation for the `fireEnemyAttacked` method that changes the character object according to whatever change arguments for the enemy object were passed to `fireEnemyAttacked`.

```
class Character : public enemyChangeListener{

 //your methods and members;

 void fireEnemyAttacked(/*args*/){

   //do the changes to the character.
 }
```

You instantiate an Enemy object by providing a reference to to your `Character` object (which the enemy class sees as a `enemyChangeListener` object in the constructor. This design accomplishes two things :

1. Your `Enemy` class no longer has to worry about the implementation details( such as the getter and setter methods) of your `Character` class. All it knows is that any object that wants to change itself based on some event on the enemy object will implement the required interface and handle the change themselves.
2. You can use this interface not just with the `Character` class, but any other class that may be interested in listening to changes or actions on an enemy object , and change its own state in response.

**PS: **

> A nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object.

Have you checked whether `enemyAttack` is a static function ?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
Try putting the character class above enemy OR include character.h at the top of your enemy file.

Create functions in character that are able to modify the values by passing parameters.

```
void Character::ModLife(int M)
{
    hp -= M;
}

void Character::ModAr(int Ar)
{
    Armor -= Ar;
}
```

in the function....

```
character.ModLife(5);
```

Comment: Did you read that the OPs problem lies more in getting `Enemy` to know about `Character` instances, not in having getter/setter methods.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a common file where you have a character and an enemy. In that file you should handle events like the enemy hurting the character or vice versa. Having an Enemy instance directly changed values in a character instance would require the two classes to be very tightly coupled and would be bad practice.